# Vector sorting with different objects in it

Tags: c++, sorting, object, vector

I am trying to come out with a sort function, previously, with some help, manage to do a sort that sorts base on a variable that is stored into an object vector.

PointTwoD is my object.

```
bool compare(const PointTwoD& a, const PointTwoD& b)
{ 
    return a.getcivIndex() > b.getcivIndex();
    //sort from high to low 
}

//to do the sort, i will just have to call it in my function
void Sort(vector<PointTwoD>& Vector)
{
    sort(Vector.begin(), Vector.end(), compare);
}
```

Base on this, I tried to recreate it.

ShapeTwoD is my object now, which is also a parent class.
I have 3 sub classes for polymorphism which i store the sub class objects into the vector.

```
bool compareAscend(ShapeTwoD& a, ShapeTwoD& b)
{ 
    return b.getArea() > a.getArea();       
}

bool compareDescend(ShapeTwoD& a, ShapeTwoD& b)
{ 
    return a.getArea() > b.getArea();       
}
//if i only compile this, the compiler is fine with this

void Sort(vector<ShapeTwoD*>& Vector)
{
    string choice;

    cout << "\n\na)\tSort by area (ascending)" << endl;
    cout << "b)\tSort by area (descending)" << endl;
    cout << "c)\tSort by special type and area" << endl;

    cout << "\tPlease select sort option (‘q’ to go main menu): ";
    cin >> choice;
    transform(choice.begin(), choice.end(), choice.begin(), ::tolower);

    if (choice == "a")
    {
        sort(Vector.begin(), Vector.end(), compareAscend);
        //these lines are giving the error
    }
    else if (choice == "b")
    {
        sort(Vector.begin(), Vector.end(), compareDescend);
        //these lines are giving the error
    }
}
```

But when i try to compile, the compiler will give me A LOAD of errors, which i don't understand.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: create a virtual compare function for the base class and re-implement it, if neccessary, for all other objects.

Comment: @Nidhoegger How do i do that ? I create the virtual sorting function in the base class ?

Comment: @Nidhoegger And i only want to sort base on the area which are stored in the Vector, which is why i use the `getArea()` between 2 Vectors and sort and store them back in.

Comment: Please post some of that compiler errors (not all, just a few, that we can see whats going on). Or provide a **minimal** version, so we see what the compiler is mocking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are trying to sort a `vector` containing `ShapeTwoD*`s, the compare function must work with `ShapeTwoD*` too, not `ShapeTwoD&` or `ShapeTwoD const&`.

Change

```
bool compareAscend(ShapeTwoD& a, ShapeTwoD& b)
{ 
    return b.getArea() > a.getArea();       
}
```

to

```
bool compareAscend(ShapeTwoD* a, ShapeTwoD* b)
{ 
    return b->getArea() > a->getArea();       
}
```

Change `compareDescend` similarly.

Comment: Thanks, even after reading on pointers tutorial, i don't quite understand what are the `*` and `&` fully